# Python catch jQuery .post()

Tags: jquery, python, json, .post

I need to post JSON object from webpage to GAE Python

**website**

```
$('#save').click(function() {
    x = JSON.stringify(result);
    $.post("/save_leads", x)
    .done(function() {})
    .fail(function() { alert("error"); })
});
```

**fragment of stringified JSON object**

```
[{"adrese":"Slokas 161, Rīga, LV-1067","nosaukums":"\"Akropolis\", apbedīšanas birojs","web":"www.akropoliss.lv","talrunis":"80005580","save":true},{"adrese":"Katlakalna 11c, Rīga, LV-1073","nosaukums":"DB Schenker Loģistikas Parks un Kravu Pasaule","web":"www.dbschenker.lv","talrunis":"67800087","save":true}]
```

**python**

```
def save_leads(self):
    results = self.request.get('x')
    logging.info(len(results)) #logs as 0 :S
```

So far I've only been posting contents of the form using html, so I have no idea if I'm posting or catching it wrong.

**P.S.: I would prefer the answer that would allow me to json.loads() on Python side**

Comment: My guess is if you want to get it by the key x.. you should pass it as a data object `$.post("/save_leads", {x:x})`.. or if you might not even need to stringify it and just do `$.post("/save_leads", {x:result})`

Comment: stringified version `$.post("/save_leads", {x:x})` worked!
the `len(x)` for non-stringified version logged 0. That makes me wonder if `$.post("/save_leads", {x:result})` actually also worked and it's `len()` that doesn't work on JSON objects... have to check it out!

Comment: `result = json.load(self.request.get('x'))` results in `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'`. So either i was feeding JSON to Python incorectly or it's that i must always stringify. Anyway - stringified version works and that solves my problem for now. Thanks!

Comment: PS: So this is how data submitted from form looks like `{input_name1:value, input_name2:value}`

Comment: Oh yeah, you need to stringify it unless you specify the datatype as `json` then you don't need to stringify it because it will automatically stringify it for you.  Here's how you change the datatype. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/#example-6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to summ it all up. The right answer was:

***web***

```
$('#save').click(function() {
    y = JSON.stringify(result);
    console.log(result)
    $.post("/save_leads", {x:y})
    .done(function() {})
    .fail(function() { alert("error"); })
});
```

**server side**

```
def save_leads(self):
    result = self.request.get('x')
    result = json.loads(result)
```

If i could find a post that had answer like this, i would have to ask. So I hope this helps other `jQuery -> post(JSON) -> Python` newbs:)